# SurfaceView and error inflating class

Tags: android, surfaceview

I was trying to make an app with a custom view, and i kept getting "error inflating class".
It must be that I am missing some of the basics when it comes to custom views, but I am not sure what.  Here is a very simple program with a custom view, what more is needed to make it work?

(Notes: For the sake of this question, I put SurfaceView class inside of the Activity Class. This was not the situation in the larger application. I do not show the AndroidManifest.xml file here, but it is just what was generated by the wizard in eclipse.)

Here is the java:

```
package com.mypackage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class SimpleCustomViewActivity extends Activity {

class TheView extends SurfaceView{

    private static final String TAG = "TheView";

    public TheView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Log.i(TAG,"TheView(" + context + "," + attrs + ")");
    }

}

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_layout);
        TheView v = (TheView) findViewById(R.id.myview);
    }
}
```

Here is file res/layout/simple_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <com.mypackage.SimpleCustomView.TheView
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in xml it should be:

```
 <com.mypackage.SimpleCustomView.TheView     
    android:id="@+id/myview"     
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
 </com.mypackage.SimpleCustomView.TheView>
```

Comment: I changed the simple view app to reflect your suggestion. It still crashed. There is a long stack trace which seems to be initially set off by a ClassNotFoundException on com.mypackage.SimpleCustomViewActivity.TheView.  So I tried making the class public too, still it crashes.

Comment: Also, I notice we both wrote com.mypackage.SimpleCustomView when we mean com.mypackage.SimpleCustomViewActivity. But that particular error seems never to have been in the source code that I tested and must have been introduced when i copied it to this web form.

Comment: Ok. I got it to work.  I had to move TheView out to another file rather than have it as a subclass. Thank you very much for the help. The simplest things can sometimes wrack a developer's brains for hours. I do wish the above errors were caught at compile time.

Comment: Yes the path com.mypackage.SimpleCustomView.TheView points to a separate file class TheView. If it is an inner class in the activity then one should not use XML at all but use setContentView(new TheView(this)) or someParentLayout.addView(new TheView(this))

Answer (score 7):

When u call your own surfaceView class from the xml file u need to add the following public surfaceView creating methods:

```
public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}
```

If u are using the function setContentView(gv) you only need the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this may work though I haven't tested it:

```
<View
   class="com.mypackage.SimpleCustomView$TheView"
   id="@+id/myview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
: declare two methods and it should be public!!
```

**public** TheView(Context context)

**public** TheView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)